# Create an "sub" account on Google Analytics through an API dynamically

Tags: google-analytics, server-side, google-analytics-api

Does anyone know how (if possible) to create an account dynamically?  I have a few accounts I need to setup on Google Analytics, and I would love to not have to manually enter each one on GA's site.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

from my knowledge the analytics API only supports data exports, it doesn't allow for interactions on the accounts or profiles information ( add, edit, delete )